# Order statistics of mixed (iid as well as non iid) random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, order-statistics

Does anyone know if there are results (PDF or the CDF) on the order statistics (at least minimum or maximum) of $n$ random variables in which a few of them are i.i.d. and the rest of them are correlated identically distributed (with known covariance)?

I am aware of the results (PDF and CDF) of the order statistics of $n$ i.i.d random variables. I encounter the mixed (iid and non iid with known covariance) in my research. Do not know how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of results are you looking for? Such as bounds on probabilities, expectation etc?

Comment: I am looking for any result, in particular, the probability or cumulative distribution functions.